# How a project should be structured with Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I've used ASP.NET MVC before and now I'm looking into Backbone.js.

How a project should be structured? That is in ASP.NET MVC you can create separate files for Model, View and Controller code and there is true code separation. How do I achieve that with Backbone.js, do I just create a series of JS includes and position these in my home page index.html file?

Answer (score 1):

Backbone does not impose any specific organizational hierarchy on your application structure.
So yes, you are free to set up your application structure in whatever way you want. As far as separate files are concerned, you can definitely have (and I'd recommend you to do so) your models, views etc. in separate files. If your application is getting large with several files checkout a javascript dependency managemer/module loader eg. [Require.js](http://requirejs.org)

If you are looking for something more structured and opinionated you might take a look at one of the meta frameworks built on top of Backbone eg. Chaplin : http://chaplinjs.org/

Quoting from the Chaplin site :

> Chaplin is an architecture for JavaScript applications using the
>   Backbone.js library. Chaplin addresses Backbone’s limitations by
>   providing a lightweight and flexible structure that features
>   well-profen design patterns and best practises.

Another popular alternative is : [Backbone.marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette)

Quoting from the README.md

> Backbone.Marionette is a composite application library for Backbone.js
>   that aims to simplify the construction of large scale JavaScript
>   applications. It is a collection of common design and implementation
>   patterns found in the applications that I (Derick Bailey) have been
>   building with Backbone, and includes various pieces inspired by
>   composite application architectures, such as Microsoft's "Prism"
>   framework.

Comment: Thanks for a very comprehensive answer !

Comment: You are welcome. If you find it satisfactory you can "accept" it using the green check mark link.